# Why do they say Adora can't act?

Tags: character, reference, she-ra-and-the-princesses-of-power

In the 2018 show *She-Ra and the Princesses of Power* (a reboot of the 1984 show of a similar name), characters will sometimes say that the protagonist, Adora, can't act (sometimes "to save her life").

After binge-watching all the seasons three times I cannot recall a moment when Adora had to act or pretend which would spur the expression.

This leads me to believe it is some sort of reference.

In short, why do characters in the show *She-Ra and the Princesses of Power* sometimes say that Adora "can't act"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some collaboration it seems it might be because of

> her "performance" while meeting Bow's dads as an "academic" and because every time she has had to lie she wasn't very good at it.

Due to lack of anything better, I guess this is it. :/